# Eval src block only for certain system?

Tags: org-mode

Is there way to disable/enable source block on a certain system type?

I've tried this, it didn't work:

```
#+begin_src shell :eval (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
echo "On gnu/linux"
#+begin_src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```el
#+begin_src shell :eval (if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "yes" "no")
  echo "On gnu/linux"
#+end_src
```

The expression *is* evaluated, but the value has to be one of the values that the `:eval` header expects.